# Cannot disable DPI scaling for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, high-dpi

I would like high DPI enabled for most of the applications that I use on my 14" 1920x1080 laptop, except for a few like Visual Studio that benefits from the extra space. However, setting "disable high DPI" in compatibility does nothing. I am using Windows 8.

Comment: Synetech edited this question. I can't find a way to comment on his revision or to send him a message, so I'll post the reasoning here: The question is specific to VS 2012 (and perhaps other applications using particular frameworks eg WPF) where regular DPI compatability setting does not work. Also, it's almost certainly not specific to Windows 8, although I haven't tested it on 7/Vista.

Comment: I removed the `Windows` tag since it should only be used if it effects ALL versions of `Windows` since your using `Windows 8` only that tag applies to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i asked [Chris Jackson, the Microsoft AppCompat guy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150614095321/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/12/03/living-the-high-dpi-life.aspx); there is no way to do this.

> We don’t have such an ability, the scaled mode is what we have to handle those situations. Yes, there clearly are some things that are suboptimal about how we do that (I hate the fuzzies too), but it’s hard to get a second fix approved which technically solves the same thing since that means that engineer isn't doing something else to make the world a better place.

i also asked *nearly* the same thing [here](https://superuser.com/questions/183109/vista-7-possible-to-dpi-lie-but-without-the-scaling).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Hearing this, and hearing other comments re C# development, one gets the impression that Microsoft has no money and barely has a dozen people working for it. There is no attention to detail. Little things never get fixed. All in the name of "we don't have the resources." How inefficient is MS? Anyway, this is a bit of a big deal since I paid top dollar for the display that only benefits a few screen-hungry apps. I've turned off High DPI entirely, but why should all the other apps be tiny? Is per-app DPI so hard? Chris implies the fix is easy, but "forbidden".

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky - If you get that impression then I don't know what your hearing but its anything Microsoft is doing.  There has been hundreds of improvements between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: @Rahmound Eric Lippert answered an SO question of why C# can't infer generic types for constructors with something like, "there's no real problem, it'd be a lot like inferring them for methods. But we have limited budgets [--yeah right]. And, btw, consistency of the language is a low priority." Other examples in C# is generic type constraints for Enums and delegates, which are likewise dead-simple to implement. Or, eg, Word/Excel 2010 still has bizarre Alt+Tab behavior because noone bothered to rewrite the hacks around old MDI. Or all of Win8 that isn't Metro. The list goes on, plus this reply

Comment: @Rahmound MS's philosophy is simply this: adding new features is great. Improving the things that are already written is "a waste of our precious, miniscule resources" even when there aren't any more features to add. That is incongruent with how much money MS has, and really takes its toll when the timescale is decades. Half of Word/Excel's dialogs predate Office 95! Plus the multi-window madness. Visual Studio is a pain to use having discovered Netbeans. VS's GUI was ENTIRELY rewritten in WPF for 2010, and NOTHING OLD WAS IMPROVED. Stasis. Wonderful, comforting stasis.

Comment: MS is a large corp. Which means, in America, they have a large employee base but very few people that actually work. Everyone wants to work for M$, but no one does it for the love of coding, or very few do, anymore.

Comment: The real reason, for those that live in the real world, is that [every C# language feature starts at -100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx). Microsoft has finite resources, and a feature has to be worth it.

Answer (score 17):

**THIS IS POSSIBLE**

I tried this on my Windows 8 and it works perfectly:

1. Go to your Visual Studio Shortcut/app launcher
2. Right Click and Troubleshoot Compatibility
3. Continue Troubleshooting Program
4. Troubleshoot Program
5. Tick: Program opens but doesn't display correctly
6. Test Program..
7. Yes, Save Changes

You are all set!

Comment: Works on Visual Studio 2012 Update 5 on Windows 8

Comment: Works with VS 2015 on Windows 10, except you need to find the app launcher through your start menu and open the file location of the shortcut, because the troubleshoot compatibility menu item is only available when you right click from the shortcut in windows explorer.

Comment: Works on VS 2015 on windows 8.1.

Comment: This has been bugging me for a while now. This worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Works on VS 2017 on windows 10

Answer (score 16):

This is absolutely possible. I was using the "compatibility" settings on executables to do it but for some reason that's not available for VS. However the [equivalent registry key](https://web.archive.org/web/20160419192848/http://blogs.technet.com:80/b/mspfe/archive/2013/11/22/disabling-dpi-scaling-on-windows-8-1-the-enterprise-way.aspx) works just fine. The key is `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` and you just have to add a string value "~ HIGHDPIAWARE" (same as ticking that box in the compatibility tab of the executable's properties). Or you can just run this:

> reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "full path to Executable" /t REG_SZ /d "~ HIGHDPIAWARE"

Comment: Welcome to SU!  Link-only answers are considered a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please edit your answer and include pertinent information directly, and include the link as a source reference.

Comment: This will work specifically for VS?  I don't see what identifies the exe

Comment: Yes sorry Aleksandr SU's markup had removed the placeholder. Check the answer again.

Comment: This also works in Visual Studio 2013 btw.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2013, in the specified registry path, I have the following string key: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` with value `~ RUNASADMIN HIGHDPIAWARE` to Run as Admin and No Scaling

Comment: I can confirm that this works with VS2015 and Windows 10