# How can I run a single Windows application in High DPI mode?

Tags: windows, high-dpi

Windows has a "high DPI" feature which lets users effectively use high DPI displays, in since Windows XP.

However, many applications implemented display scaling incorrectly. In Windows Vista, they added a backwards compatibility feature which scales the application as a bitmap, resulting in blurry controls.

I would like to make my application be high-DPI aware, which means testing in high DPI mode. But switching back and forth (and logging in/out) to check if the scaling code works correctly is annoying.

Is there some way to force my application to run in high DPI mode for testing purposes?

(I am well aware that the answer may be "you can't; sorry." I worded this as a "How..." question because I don't want someone to say "Yes" and say nothing else)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set DPI of individual applications in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/66101/set-dpi-of-individual-applications-in-windows), [How to force high-dpi scaling?](http://superuser.com/questions/127214/how-to-force-high-dpi-scaling) ...

Comment: @Karan: Agreed. Also voted to close.

Comment: Wait, you work *for* Microsoft? *You* should be asking company experts about questions like these or posting on some internal mailing list and giving *us* useful tips and answers!

Comment: @Karan: It doesn't work like that. It's a company of 40,000 developers; there's no magic system that lets one figure out exactly which of the other 39,999 one needs to talk with about a feature. Nor do people in the Windows group treat people outside the Windows group like insiders, even if I knew with whom I should speak.

Comment: Ah well, there goes our dream of obtaining answers to some *really* burning questions about Windows and its oddities! :) Was just hoping there might be a mailing list where you guys can at least post queries and hopefully receive informed answers.

Comment: @Karan: You're more likely to get answers posting comments in Raymond's suggestion box :)

Comment: Yeah, but the 2-3 year wait is a killer! Thankfully [he](http://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) does answer queries on SO, but of course those have to be programming-related.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Properties for your application's executable file and switch to *Compatibility* tab and check `Disable display scaling on high DPI settings` option.

Comment: This disables scaling, but doesn't cause the application to run in high DPI mode.

Comment: Why can't you enable high dpi by default and disable it only for problematic apps? (and at the same time submit bug report to app developer to fix that issue)

Comment: Because I don't want to run in high DPI mode; it isn't something I have any desire to use. I just want to make sure my app doesn't fail for those users who are using high DPI.

Comment: (Also, there isn't a way to disable it for problematic apps; this setting disables display scaling, it doesn't disable high DPI for the app itself)

Comment: Ah, well, you didn't mention that you still wanted to run in low-dpi and it was testing for other users.

Comment: I don't see how my question "Is there some way to force my application to run in high DPI mode for testing purposes?" could be interpreted any other way.