# Turn OFF High DPI Scaling on a DLL file - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, dpi, high-dpi, windows-photo-viewer

High DPI scaling can be a pain sometimes, normally you just go to the **EXE** and turn it off [manually](https://superuser.com/questions/127214/how-to-force-high-dpi-scaling). But how can you turn it off for a **DLL** file?

My problem is that I want to to turn it off for **Windows Photo Viewer** which it appears is a DLL file rather than an exe!

Why I want to do it for a Windows' own app? Well because sometimes their own apps don't work properly as they have admitted [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2900023).

---

Also, can someone tell me exactly which DLL file is Windows Photo Viewer. Different sources on the web give me these 2 files: *(the first one looks obvious though!)*

1. C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.[dll](https://superuser.com/questions/947672/how-to-bring-back-photo-viewer-in-windows-10)
2. C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.[dll](http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/where-is-windows-picture-and-fax-viewer-program-located-370165/)

Comment: *shimgvw.dll isn't Windows Photo Viewer.*  It is a file for `Windows Picture and Fax Viewer` which was part of Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem of high DPI briefly explained:

According to [this](http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/) site:

> The problem in Windows 10:
> When you have a widescreen, with a
> resolution of 1920x1080 or higher or a bit lower, in Windows Vista, 7,
> 8 and 8.1 you would put your DPI scaling to 125% or higher to make
> text and images appear larger and more easy to read.  But when you put
> the DPI scaling to 125% in Windows 10, you see in a lot of dialogs and
> windows the font gets very blurry.

And then it continues:

> At some point we can understand Windows why they changed the DPI
> scaling in Windows 10. **It is probably ment to support mobile devices
> more easy.**  But if you like to **use your Desktop as a Desktop**, and you
> demand high quality only. Then you can use this fix until Microsoft
> has addressed this issue.

## Solution:

So, if you use your Windows 10 only for a Desktop purpose, you can download their free program called XPExplorer from [here](http://www.xpexplorer.com/installers/Windows10_DPI_FIX.exe).

## Why use this program and not some registry change?

The site answers:

> Why this is a small software program, and not some 'Registry Tweak' is
> because when you manually adjust the DPI settings at your 'Windows
> Registry'. **Windows will reset your dpi settings every 2 reboots**. Which
> means you would have to adjust the registry again (Microsoft forces
> you almost to use its new DPI scaling method).**

I can confirm this solution works well (as well after reboots) on my Windows 10 setup.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The dll file is located here in windows 10 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer

Photo Viewer dll is launched by good old "rundll32.exe"

Looks like you can disable DPI scaling for "rundll32.exe" by adding the following registry key:
"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe"
to

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]

and set its value to "HIGHDPIAWARE"

Source [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-photo-viewer-disable-dpi-scaling-slideshow/9ab28108-5d6c-43dc-b149-8b468f1d56e9?auth=1)

I haven't tried it myself yet as Win10 photo app does the work for me

Comment: I can confirm that this method does work. The value needs to be set to `~ HIGHDPIAWARE`.